# arm Inputting an integer using system interrupt (swi 0)

Tags: arm

does anyone know the code for inputting an integer in ARM? this is what I have so far

```
    .text .global main
    main:
    mov r0, #0
    ldr r1, =inputint
    mov r2, #4
    ldr R7, #3
    swi 0

   .data
   inputint: .asciz "%d"
```

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: if so https://github.com/auselen/arm-printf